# Querying a batch of addresses in SQL

Tags: sql

We were in a hurry but I really want to know a better solution for querying 50 addresses for the batching we do.  What we ended up doing was hashing address1, address2, city, zip, state and then doing a query where c.hash in (list of hashes) which is a rather simple SQL query.

I did not know if there was a query we can do with where all those columns are in that set in SQL.

How would someone do this possibly without using the hash column?